# Access and IIf statements

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 fields that need to be checked, option 1, option 2 and option 3. all are fields in a table. I want to add another field called premium which will apply a discount if all the option boxes are ticked. Whats the syntax for this?

What ive tried is something like this (this wasnt my final version ive done this so you can see the logic a bit easier)

```
iif([op1]&&[op2]&&[op3]="True",[premium]=[final]-10,[premium]=35)
```

If all these 3 options have been checked then the final price is X otherwise it is Y

Comment: Take out the `="True"` or at least remove the quotes. Change `&&` to `AND`. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3

Comment: thanks! My next bit is how can i reference values within the main table, for eg, i want to premium to be the full total [Price]-30. when i do this access doesnt seem to like it and wont let me reference the value of the field for this record. Is there a way to do this

Comment: You need to add might context to your question. Is this on a form, in a query...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this in mind - as ControlSource for Premium:

```
=IIf([op1]=True & [op2]=True & [op3]=True,[final]-10,35)
```

Comment: thanks mate, yep, this is it, i just couldnt locate properly the syntax, after 30 minutes of looking around using keywords like And and being specific on how you say True and not TRUE or otherways seemed to start working

Answer (score 0):

IIf(([op1]=True) And ([op2]=True) And ([op3]=True),([Price]-10),[price])